# how to get selected text from bash output using iperf

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to grab only selected text from perf output in this example using ubuntu linux 14.04.

```
~$ iperf -c xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -r
```

creates this output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------ Server listening on TCP port 5001 TCP window size: 85.3 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------ Client connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, TCP port 5001 TCP window size: 48.1 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------ [  5] local xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 51684 connected with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 5001 [ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth [  5]  0.0-10.0 sec 
82.8 MBytes  69.3 Mbits/sec [  4] local xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 5001 connected with xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 60267 [  4]  0.0-10.1 sec   105 MBytes  87.7 Mbits/sec
```

I want to grab `69.3` and `87.7.`  before `Mbits/sec`

Otherwise to grab bandwidth i could use:

```
$ iperf -c xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -r -y C
```

creating this output:

```
20150228152825,192.168.0.50,54278,192.168.0.110,5001,3,0.0-10.0,1034158080,827149205
20150228152835,192.168.0.50,5001,192.168.0.110,59625,5,0.0-10.0,776732672,621025632
```

And get the last digit after the last comma i each line. I just can't figure it out using grep, sed or awk.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cut will do this very well

```
iperf -c xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -r -y C|cut -d',' -f9
```

Comment: Yes it works perfekt. How can the two output be saved in var1 and var2?

Comment: `iperf_data=$(iperf -c $IP1 -r -y C -L 41500|cut -d',' -f9)` 
How to insert the two variables i two separate variables like download and upload ?

Comment: `read a b < <(iperf -c 192.168.0.8 -r -y C|cut -d',' -f9|paste -s)`

Comment: works on command line but not in shell script i get this: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Comment: @JohnHenriksen : are you using the first line of your script as `#!/bin/bash`? If so, tell us output of `echo $BASH_VERSION`. I'm guessing you have `#!/bin/sh`, and you'll have to change that. (You need to learn to write your question in 1 complete statement and not ask for "extras" after the fact ;-) OK?) Good luck to all.

Comment: first line is: #!/bin/sh. My bash version is:4.3.11(1)-release on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @JohnHenriksen : try changing to `#!/bin/bash`. Good luck.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks guys :-) This is my first question in this forum so please accept my apology for not asking the right way. I'll do that the next time. Thanks again.

Comment: @JohnHenriksen : Sorry, rereading above, I realize that was a bit harsh. You did a good job showing your data source, your required output and that you had tried to solve your problem. Keep posting! Good luck to all.